# move menu dropdown to left

Tags: html, css

I have top menu with drop down navigation(sub menu) and drop down comes right side of main menu.

css:

```
ul.dropdown ul {
width: 220px;
visibility: hidden;
position: absolute;
top: 100%;
left: 0;
}
```

How can change position to left for a last menu because if i hover on last menu, drop-down comes with horizontal scroll because there is no space on right side to display menu?

Please help

Comment: Can you set up a fiddle to play with?

Comment: Please accept my first correct answer (of which the others took and tried to improve) for future viewers, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
ul.dropdown li {
   position: relative;
}

ul.dropdown li ul {
   position: absolute;
   top: 20px; /* assign the correct value of the top line height */
   left: 0px;
}
```

This should work^^ When assigning `position:absolute;` to an child element of an element with `position:relative` the absolute positioning is relative to its parent and not to the body.

My fault, somehow overread the last part with "last child".

This could work:

```
ul.dropdown li:last-of-type ul {
   position:absolute;
   left:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery to fix the problem,try this

```
$(function(){
    $(".dropdown:last").css("left","-120px");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `last-child` selector to set `right` property instead of `left`:

```
.dropdown > li:last-child:hover ul {
    left: auto;
    right: 0;
}
```

You don't provide a fiddle so I've set up this simple example to demonstrate the principle: http://jsfiddle.net/6eBd2/