# Point Theme - Wordpress: Menu

Tags: html, css, wordpress, drop-down-menu, menu

I am not a professional programmer but can understand HTML and CSS and tinker around with them. I am using the Point theme on Wordpress. This is the site I am working on (site still under construction).

http://reachout.ind.in/

My doubts are about the main menu on top:

1. If you look at the last item - "Helplines" when you hover on it, you will see that the child category list has been cut off by the width of the parent block. I saw this thread: [move menu dropdown to left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15920499/move-menu-dropdown-to-left) but I cannot make out which "parent block" I should be working with. I would paste the code here, but there are way too many styles in the stylesheet. I have tried looking at the "Inspect Element" feature by Chrome, and I see that the wrapper class is:

   ```
   <li id="menu-item-153" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page">
       <a href="http://reachout.ind.in/helplinesdirectory/suicide-helplines/">Suicide Helplines<br>
          <span class="sub"></span>
       </a> 
   </li>
   ```

The "menu-item-object-page" class is not in the stylesheet.

How do I fix this?

2. When I add more elements to the menu, it spills over to the next line (obviously) and the alignment gets all messed up. How do I add new elements to the menu and retain the style?

Will be glad to paste specific code here if anyone can tell me what to paste! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the navigation is designed for dropdowns to open towards the right, which is normal, however a pain for the last item in the list. This is why in web architecture, you never want the page content to extent to the absolute edges of the screen. You want some gutter on the sides to allow for right floated navigations with dropdowns etc. So, the way I see it, you have 2 options:

1. go back to the left floated navigation. It will save you a headache specially since you don't do this professionally. remove the float:right; on this css portion of your style.css

   ```
    .secondary-navigation {
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto;
        max-width: 100%;
        /*float: right;*/
     }
   ```
2. remove the overflow:hidden from the content body here:

   ```
   .main-container {
      width: 980px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      /* overflow: hidden; */
      padding: 0;
      ...
   }
   ```

Comment: This is great help, thanks so much! I did the first one.

Comment: Then you should mark it as an answer so that future users may benefit